# Tips on improving calculation speed in Access

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access

I'm using MS Access 2013 (without any access to other SQL programs).

I have to filter data, based on daily breakdowns across 30 years (10800 rows to start with) for more than 50 customers (540.000 rows in total). **I have an issue with the speed of my queries**. After a few joins and filters the whole thing takes seconds to run. To speed up the calculation I tried:

1. breaking queries down (using as few joins as possible)
2. filtering for 'active data' only;
3. aggregating iteration queries;
4. indexed the dates (as Integers).

In need to add, for each calendar date, the summed DealValue, aggregated by Customer, for it's 'active period' (each day between the StartDate and EndDate of the given Deal). The deals may spread over 30 years. Looks like that **LEFT JOIN** is causing all the slow-down.

My final query looks like:

```
SELECT QMaster.CalDate, 
       QDeals.CustomerID, 
       Sum(IIf([QDeals]![Limit]="S",[QDeals.DealValue],0)) AS S, 
       Sum(IIf([QDeals]![Limit]="L",[QDeals.DealValue],0)) AS L
FROM QMaster 
     LEFT JOIN TDeals 
     ON (QMaster.CalDate> QDeals.DealStartDate) 
        AND (QMaster.CalDate< QDeals.DealEndDate)
GROUP BY QMaster.CalDate, QDeals.CustomerID;
-- where QMaster (540.000 rows) / QDeals (> 10.000 rows) / calculation time 5<>7s
-- the query may contain typos as I had to change the name description for disclosure.
```

Any tips on how to replace that LEFT JOIN?

Or any other speed improvements prior to this query?

I want to add an 'interactive' Access form over my 'master' query and that's turning to be very slow (not user friendly).

Comment: Why don't you have a `CustomerId` in the `QMaster` table?

Comment: Is your database file local to your machine or on a network drive? Remember that all processing by MS-Access is performed locally even when the data is on a network drive, possibly thousands of miles away. Thus all data for evey table must be retrieved across the network at each stage of the query.

Comment: If your query is bringing you the right data, then Indexing is one of your best choices.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens currently I have it setup locally (and it takes ages). But at the end the goal is to work with a BE/FE (with network/backend) with locally/frontend).

Comment: @GordonLinoff QMaster only holds active Calendar Dates that are pre-selected to 'filter' the data (when deals are active). Thus I reduce the timespan by app 5 years.

Comment: Please verify that you need all 30 years worth of data.

Comment: Does the Inner Join quickly enough ??? if does you could use an inner join + union to a second query/temporary table

Comment: @BruceMartin I don't know if MSAccess can use temp tables @/#. Still I will try a similar workaround. Tanks!

Comment: @DanBracuk I don't need all of them, so I truncate the period not covered by deals in my QMaster. Still, there are at least 25 year worth of data :/

Comment: @Takedasama poor wording on my part,If you are using VBA you can create a Table that you only use on a temporary basis. It is worth checking If the inner join is fast enough, if it is it will open other options